# How to propagate viewpager's onPageSelected to a custom view inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

So I have this structure: an Activity that has a ViewPager of Fragments, and on these Fragments I have a custom view. The custom view needs to know every time its parent fragment is selected by the ViewPager. What would be the best way to implement this behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: Through an interface callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fragment you should write a method that puts the number of the page you want

```
int mCurrent;
Fragment newInstance(int current)
{
    Fragment f = new Fragment();


    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("current", current);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mCurrent  = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("current") : 1;

}
```

then in your pager activity make an inner class for the adapter that will looks like :

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return new Fragment().newInstance(mPager.getCurrentItem());
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
    }
```

thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

On your ViewPager, set an OnPageChangeListener. When a new page is selected, call into your FragmentPagerAdapter. Inside your FragmentPagerAdapter, you should keep a reference to the Fragment containing the view you want to update. Call into that Fragment to update the view.